# Limit of pandas HDFStore

Tags: pandas, hdf, hdfstore

I am planning to use Pandas HDFStore as temporary file for out of core csv operations.

(csv --> HDFStore --> Out of core operation in pandas).

Just wondering :

- Limit in size of HDF5 for real life practical usage on 1 machine 
     (not the theoritical one....)
- Cost of operation for pivot tables (100 columns, fixed VARCHAR, numerical).
- Whether I would need to switch to Postgres (load csv into Postgres) and DB stuff...

Tried to find on google some benchmark limit size vs computation time for HDF5, but could not find any.

Total size of csv is around 500Go - 1To (uncompressed).

Comment: I think there is no limit - see [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/limits.html), only limited is your memory.

Comment: Hmmm, I think very hard question but obviously `pivot` operations consumed much memory . The best is try and test it if possible.